# Kohana Dynamic Routes

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

How do you set dynamic routes like this:

```
/admin/user/edit -> controller=admin_user, action=edit
/admin/user/view -> controller=admin_user, action=view
/admin/page/edit -> controller=admin_page, action=edit
```

Where `/admin/page` converts to controller `admin_page`,
or automatically: `/admin/(.*)` to `admin_$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all your `admin` controllers into `admin` directory so your controllers would have names like `user`, `page` etc.

Structure would be like:

```
controller/
    admin/
        user.php
        page.php
```

Route:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin/<controller>/<action>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'admin',
    ));
```

Comment: that works, but somehow it bugs out and not executing the regular kohana flow because i have a 'default' route right below it.

Comment: default route must be in the end of route list.